# how to edit wheel names

Tags: python, python-wheel

Is it possible to rename a wheel built with `python setup.py bdist_wheel` to a actual meaningful name?

I kmow the name `pytest_html-1.19.1.dev11+g8ae5f59-py2.py3-none-any.whl` is both apealing and meaningful as it tells important things such as the origin version and stuff, but I would like it to be called, or at least have a prefix of "fix for ___".

Can that be done?

Comment: There is a chance that adding such a string messes up package managers such as pip, and they won't be able to tell what package it belongs to, or what the precise version is. It's probably best to have such information as bugfixes in a readme file or change log for the respective version on a website: this is what practically all projects do.

Comment: I know for a fact that changing the name completly would not work, howver, I'm intersted in keeping the data `pip install` would want, just moving it aside so the guy who installs it would understand what he is installing